# Unified path to require a file in PHP from all folders

Tags: php, path, directory, require

I have the current tree.

```
/edu/index.php
/edu/Classes/Connection.php
/edu/Classes/User.php
/edu/Handlers/Post.php
```

When I need to use functions from `Connection.php` and `User.php` inside index.php, I require them using:

```
require_once './Classes/Connection.php';
require_once './Classes/User.php';
```

But some functions from `User.php` also needs functions from `Connection.php` to work, so since `index.php` is where the requests come from, I require `Connection.php` inside `User.php` using:

```
require_once './Classes/Connection.php';
```

But sometimes I need to use the same functions from `Post.php`, so

`require_once './Classes/Connection.php';` inside `User.php` does not work if `Post.php` is the file sending requests.

Isn't there a unified path or solution so that I can be able to require the file from any place inside my project in the same way? I would really like to avoid a solution such as...

```
public function UserFunction($path){
  require_once $path;
}
```

And change the parameter on each call depending on my position inside the project folder.

Comment: define a constant of your absolute path configuration and prefix all your require_once paths with that constant.

Comment: Or better yet, use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files you are trying to include are mostly classes, it would probably be best to implement the [`__autoload`](http://www.php.net/__autoload) function. When you instantiate a class, if the class hasn't been defined, then the `__autoload` method is called with the class name so you can include the file. If you create a simple standard, like all classes reside in the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/classes/'` folder and the filename is the same as the class name like `ClassName.php`, you can dynamically load in any classes as they are needed.

Also, generally looked down upon but I figured I would mention it because I hadn't seen it offered yet. There is the [`set_include_path()`](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) function you can call that will allow you to set the path(s) that php looks when including a file. HOWEVER, this can cause some trouble. As an example, my work hosts several sites under sub-domains each with their own document root. Under the document root each site has its own "includes" folder. Well some genius about 8 years ago set the include path in the global apache config to `/var/www/site1/includes;/var/www/site2/includes...etc`. Problem is that when a file exists with the same name in `site1` as `site2` and you try to include it, you will always include the file from `site1` because php will find the file there and stop looking. It has caused some small headaches from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Your best best is to include relative to `__DIR__`  to get a file relative to another file.

Other good points that you can include from are

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

or make your own using htaccess.

in .htaccess put

```
SetEnv MY_INCLUDE_PATH "/path/to/my/php/files";
```

then in php

```
include ($_SERVER["MY_INCLUDE_PATH"]."/Connection.php");
```